# how can i solve binary system in c++?

Tags: c++

how can i see the answer when i need to solve the decimal code to binary code?

Comment: Is this homework, or a badly worded question?

Comment: @EboMike That's an inclusive or, right?

Comment: i hope you realize your question makes no sense

Comment: I guess he wants to see the binary representation of some decimal number. Dont think he could word it worst.

Comment: @Izno, there's no limit to how terrible a question can be. This one admittedly ranks pretty high up though.

Comment: I'm sure English is not the poster's native language. If you can't understand the question then it should be closed, but you do it without all the piling on.

Comment: @GregS That's okay, he probably won't understand my inclusive or joke, so no harm done.

Comment: Na @John ist vielleicht ein Widerling. Macht sich einfach über Leute lustig weil er glaubt sie verstehen ihn nicht...

Comment: ..@deceze ... en deceze is misschien een slimmerik

Comment: @0A0D Deutsch und Holländisch sind zu nah verwandt um den gewünschten Effekt zu erzielen... ;-)

Answer (score 4):

`decimal code` to `binary code`? i think that you mean `decimal number` to `binary number`, so use std::bitset e.g.

```
#include <bitset>
...
int i = 49;
std::cout << std::bitset<sizeof(i)*8>(i).to_string() << std::endl;
```